# How to Combine/merge two image using PHP imagecopy() or imagecopymerge()?

Tags: php

Please help to combine three jpg images using php image processing functions  imagecopy, imagecopymerge

[image: b.jpg]

image 1-    b.jpg

[image: l.jpg]
image 2-   l.jpg

[image: r.jpg]

image3:         r.jpg

output look like
[image]

I tried some example codes of the PHP  functions  imagecopy() or imagecopymerge() 
but not working with my images.

Answer (score 4):

Could you give more information about: "not working"

I would suggest you to take a look at: [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

For the code, you have to load the images as image ressources, so you can use something like:

```
$im1 = imagecreatefrompng($path.'image1.png');
$im2 = imagecreatefrompng($path.'image2.png');

imagecopyresampled($im1,$im2,250,150,0,0,100,150,100,150);
unset($im2);
$im3 = imagecreatefrompng($path.'image3.png');

imagecopyresampled($im1,$im3,550,150,0,0,100,150,100,150);
unset($im3);
```

So $im1 now have the 3 images.

Just make sure to unset the image ressources, because you will run out of memory really fast.

Edit: I used imagecopyresampled because image 2-3 seem smaller on the last image, I don't know how more resource intensive it is, I guess imagecopymerge could work too.

Comment: I tried this code: 


<?php
$im1 = imagecreatefrompng('image1.png');
$im2 = imagecreatefrompng('image2.png');

imagecopyresampled($im1,$im2,250,150,0,0,100,150,100,150);
unset($im2);
$im3 = imagecreatefrompng('image3.png');

imagecopyresampled($im1,$im3,550,150,0,0,100,150,100,150);
unset($im3);
?>

but getting blank page as output

Comment: Yes, the image is created but you don't show it on the page.

Try to add:
    `header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im1);`

Comment: Also if you want to output a file, you can just use `imagepng('images/name.png');` Without the `header` part.